# Produce simple HTML from DOCX using DOCX4J

Tags: java, html, docx, docx4j

I am trying to convert a .docx file to html using docx4j. However, when I convert the document to html I am left with a lot of html tags that are unnecessary. For example: 
 
  `<p class="Heading1 Normal DocDefaults "><span class="" style="font-family: 'Cambria';">This is a heading</span></p>`
 
 The conversion produces the above result for a heading that was present in my word document. Ideally I would like the class tags and styling tags removed with just a simple `<h1>` tag to denote the fact that it is a heading.
 Is there any way to modify the code so that this can be achieved using Docx4j?

Comment: I do have some code which might help, will need to dig it up....

Comment: Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can find the ancient code for what it is worth at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-export-html-oldschool .. you might modify it to work with docx4j 6.0.1, or maybe we should simply add an option to the existing 6.0.1 code to use h tags for headings.